# automatic assembly copy issue in Visual Studio 2008

Tags: visual-studio-2008, copy, projects-and-solutions

When I started to develop with .NET under VS2008 recently, I was very happy to see that all of the dependencies automagically got copied to my application's bin/debug folder upon compilation.  This is fantastic.  I never even bothered to look into how / why this is done.

Yesterday, I decided to make another plugin very similar to an existing one, so I literally copied the folder and all of project files, then renamed the folder and manually edited the project files and file references.  I also changed the assembly's GUID.

Everything builds fine, but this particular assembly is never copied into my application's bin/debug folder.  It is marked as a dependency of my app as well.

What did I miss here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you should go to reference properties pages and check if the "Copy Local" property of the reference is set to true
regards